# Capybara convert html tags to html entities written in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I have some html tags written in javascript code and when running the code in browser it works fine but when the same code run with capybara then the html tags has been converted to html entities.

here is the code that is working fine when executing in browser

```
var groups = [], prev_element = 0;
groups[0] = "<option value=''>Select Group</option><option value=1>Administrators</option><option value=2>Editors</option><option value=3>Managers</option><option value=4>group 1</option><option value=5>Group a1</option><option value=6>Group a2</option><option value=7>Group a3</option><option value=8>b1</option><option value=9>b2</option><option value=10>b3</option>";
```

But with capybara the same code is complied in to

```
var groups = [], prev_element = 0;
groups[0] = "&lt;option value=''&gt;Select Group&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=1&gt;Administrators&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=2&gt;Editors&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=3&gt;Managers&lt;/option&gt;";
```

And this things breaks the test case.

Comment: use String#html_safe method.

Comment: tried but still the behavior is same.

Comment: Which driver are using in second case? How do you got that code?